Can PhpStorm fill in metods missing named parameters?
If there is  a way  PhpStorm 2024.1 having code with some function, where named parameters were not set, like :
https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/i_DudPK1SomwFi3WZCDhYw.png
to fill all missing named parameters? I prefer to set these missing named parameters automatically, not manually one by one ?
I search in options and did noy find something like that. Maybe some external plugins ?

As far as I understand this question -- such intentions are available.
But it is unlikely that they can be used in some batch fixing/automatic manner.
Perhaps some code fixing specific tools will be able to help you instead: Rector or some PHP_CodeSniffer / PHP CS Fixer or alike (just a thought, never looked into this myself).

Case 1: No named parameters used
<?php

class Test {
  public function test(string $name, string $target) {
  }

  public function test2() {
      $this->test('A', 'Target');
  }
}


Case 2: Partial usage of the named parameters
<?php

class Test {
  public function test(string $name, string $target) {
  }

  public function test2() {
      $this->test('A', target: 'Target');
  }
}


Case 3: Another partial usage of the named parameters
<?php

class Test {
  public function test(string $name, string $target) {
  }

  public function test2() {
      $this->test(name: 'A', 'Target');
  }
}


